# Python: Open and write to a .txt file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new to python and so I'm trying to make an ATM (simulator I guess). One of the functions is to register, and so I'm trying to save the usernames in a .txt file for reference (passwords will come later of course), but for some reason it won't work.

```
def atm_register():
print "To register, please choose a username."

username = raw_input('> ')

with open("users.txt") as f:
    f.write(username, "a")
```

It tells me, that the file is not open for writing.
Btw, the users.txt file is in the same directory as the program.

Comment: `with open('filename','w') as f:`. look into the [mode parameter in the `open()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open)

Comment: If you want to write to the script directory, first `import os` and then `open(os.path.join(os.path.basename(__file__), "users.txt"), "a")`. That builds a path name off of the script directory not the user's current working directory.

Comment: Unless you want to lose data each run, use `a` not `w`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you're calling `f.write(username, "a")` and file `write()` only takes one parameter - the text to write - I guess you intend the `"a"` to *append* to the file?

That goes in the `open()` call; other answers telling you to use `open(name, "w")` are bad advice, as they will overwrite the existing file. And you might want to write a newline after the username, too, to keep the file tidy. e.g.

```
with open("users.txt", "a") as f:
    f.write(username + "\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be:

```
open("users.txt","w")
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
with open("users.txt","a") as f:
      f.write(username)
```

instead of

```
with open("users.txt") as f:
     f.write(username, "a")
```

hope this helps!

Comment: @Piethon if  this worked you can hit the check mark near this answer to mark the question as solved

Answer (score 0):

You must open the file in write mode. See [the documentation for open](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open)

`open('users.txt', 'w')` should work.