# Writing to a text file program: convert from Python 2 to Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I want to convert this from Py2:

```
with open(path, "wb") as f1:
        for i in w_vectors:
            print >>f1, i, " ".join(map(str, numpy.round(w_vectors[i], decimals=6)))
```

to Py3:

```
with open(path, "wb") as f1:
        for i in w_vectors:
            print (f1, i, " ".join(map(str, numpy.round(w_vectors[i], decimals=6))))
    
f1.close()
```

but it's not saving to the text file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Open and write to a .txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34010106/python-open-and-write-to-a-txt-file)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to redirect 'print' output to a file using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152762/how-to-redirect-print-output-to-a-file-using-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `file` keyword parameter to `print` in Python 3.

```py
print(i, " ".join(...), file=f1)
```

Answer (score 2):

For Python 2 you could use print to write to files but in Python 3 here is how you would do it instead:

```
with open(path, "wb") as f1:
    for i in w_vectors:
        f1.write(i, " ".join(map(str, numpy.round(w_vectors[i], decimals=6))))
```

And you do not have to use f1.close when using "with" because "with" takes care of it by itself.